# In which language was X3tC originally designed?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I'm asking because basically I want to know which language I should pick with German being my mother language while I prefer original language versions, but that's probably too subjective...

Since egosoft is a German developer, I wonder if X3TC was developed for German or English play originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was originally released in English, according to [this post](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=214852) on their forums:

> The English language version of X³: Terran Conflict will be available from retail outlets on October 10th, and you can pre-order from the Egosoft Online Shop NOW. X³: Terran Conflict will also be available for pre-load from Steam starting one week before release.

However, comments on [another post](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=301758) suggest that perhaps both languages were available at launch:

> Yes, during the installing process, your computer ask you, what languages you would like to install

and [this post](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=292963) seems to support that theory:

> Wenn die deutsche Sprachdateien installiert wurden, kannst du die Spiel-Sprache, wie im FAQ-Artikel Ich habe mehrere Sprachen installiert. Wie ändere ich sie? beschrieben, auf Deutsch umstellen.
>   (roughly: If the German language files are installed, you can switch the language in the game to German, as described in the FAQ article "I have multiple languages ​​installed. How do I change it?")

Note that neither post specifically says German was available at launch, but I was not able to find evidence that the German-language version was released later.

Answer (score 2):

As a german player, I rather play in german, since the voice overs all have a german accent. So yes, the "original language" of the game is german.